# Use Google App Script to prevent user opening url link in Sheets if site is already open in another browser tab

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a Google Sheet that contains numerous hyperlinks.

I'd like to prevent the user from opening multiple instances of the same site.

ie. user clicks the hyperlink in one cell which opens the linked site in a new tab, then attempts to click the same hyperlink while the first new tab is still open - I'd like a dialogue box to appear saying that they cannot open this second new tab until they have closed the first one.

Is this possible via Google App Script?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd be real surprised if it's possible with GAS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. GAS has no access to your browser data and cannot know what tabs are open.Moreover, GAS has no way of intercepting hyperlink clicks from within a spreadsheet, it can only do that in a side bar, modal (or modeless) dialog, a custom or an add-on menu  or an image with a script attached to it.